# Deal on Fed removes obstacle

Tags: word-usage

Does "Fed" refer to "Federal Reserve"? Or refer to "Federal Government"?

> **Deal on Fed removes obstacle** to agreement on COVID relief

> WASHINGTON (AP) — Top congressional lawmakers struck a late-night agreement on the last major obstacle to a COVID-19 economic relief package costing nearly $1 trillion, clearing the way for votes as early as Sunday.
> .......
> The breakthrough involved **a fight over Federal Reserve** emergency powers that was defused by an odd couple: the Senate’s top Democrat and a senior conservative Republican.

> Source:  [Associated Press](https://apnews.com/article/ap-top-news-pat-toomey-coronavirus-pandemic-75064ab1007dde0a1411c204df83e888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your paragraph you quoted, it is evident that the title refers to the "Federal Reserve".

I did a quick search and found another article that corroborates this. From [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/19/us/politics/stimulus-deal-congress.html):

> **Senators broke through an impasse late Saturday night over a Republican effort to curtail the powers of the Federal Reserve**, clearing away what had been seen as the final hurdle to a deal on a $900 billion stimulus package as lawmakers raced against a Sunday-night deadline to avoid a government shutdown.

> *(emphasis mine)*

Additionally, the "Federal Reserve" can be referred to as "the Fed". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve):

> The Federal Reserve System (also known as the Federal Reserve or simply the Fed) ...

It is rare to use "Fed" to refer to the Federal Government. (Personally, I do not recall such usage.)